# Как получить доступ к файлам в ext4.hvdx

Tags: windows-10, wsl

Есть проблема. Сдох комп, на котором был wsl. Накопитель живой, файл ext4.vhdx целый, но я не могу открыть его на другом компе. Что делал:

1. Установил wsl, установил распределение, попытался "подсунуть" виртуальны диск со сдохшего  компа. Не помогло - пишет отказано в доступе
2. Поставил ubuntu в hyper-v, подключил ext4.vhdx.Не помогло - ubuntu диск не видит.

ЗЫ: --export последний раз делал несколько месяцев назад, так что не вариант

Answer (score 0):

Блин, все оказалось очень просто - 7-zip

ext4.vhdx можно открыть в 7-zip и достать все нужные файлы

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).